# How to split delimited String to multiple rows in Hive using lateral view explode

Tags: hive, hive-udf

I have a table in Hive as below -

```
create table somedf 
(sellers string , 
 orders int 
)

insert into somedf values
('1--**--2--**--3',50),
('1--**--2', 10)
```

The table has a column called sellers and it is delimited by the characters described in the insert statement. I would like to split the sellers into multiple rows so that it looks like below -

```
exploded_sellers orders
1                 50
2                 50
3                 50
1                 10
2                 10
```

I am trying to use `lateral view explode()` function in Hive but unable to get the results. I am using the below query -

```
select exploded_sellers, orders
from somedf
lateral view outer explode(split(sellers,'\\--*.*\\*.*--')) t1 as exploded_sellers
```

which gives me below results as output -

```
exploded_sellers orders
1                 50
3                 50
1                 10
2                 10
```

This result does not split Row 1`('1--**--2--**--3',50)` from the table as desired and ends up in producing only 2 rows instead of 3.

Is there any other function that is needed for this task?
Does `lateral view explode()` only work on arrays ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern passed into `split` is incorrect. `*` character needs to be escaped. No need to escape `-`.

Use

```
select exploded_sellers, orders
from somedf
lateral view outer explode(split(sellers,'--\\*\\*--')) t1 as exploded_sellers
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work too. It expects two occurrences of * in the middle.

```
select exploded_sellers, orders
from somedf
lateral view outer explode(split(sellers,'--\\*{2}--')) t1 as exploded_sellers;
```